# CommandParameter binding in DialogViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Consider this simple `ViewModel`:

```
public class AboutViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxWebBrowserTask _webBrowserTask;
    public AboutViewModel(IMvxWebBrowserTask webBrowserTask) { _webBrowserTask = webBrowserTask; }

    private MvxCommand<string> _showInStoreCommand;
    public ICommand ShowInStoreCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _showInStoreCommand = _showInStoreCommand ?? new MvxCommand<string>(DoShowInStoreCommand);
            return _showInStoreCommand;
        }
    }

    private void DoShowInStoreCommand(string url)
    {
        _webBrowserTask.ShowWebPage(url);
    }

    public string Wp8StoreUrl
    {
        get { return "http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=myappid"; }
    }

    public string AndroidStoreUrl
    {
        get { return "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mypackagename"; }
    }

    public string TouchStoreUrl
    {
        get { return "http://itunes.com"; }
    }
}
```

Which I want to bind in a `MvxDialogViewController` and I write something like this:

```
Root = new RootElement
{
    new Section()
    {
        new StringElement("Show in App Store").Bind(bindings, e => e.SelectedCommand, vm => vm.ShowInStoreCommand, new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), ViewModel.TouchStoreUrl),
    }
}
```

Why does this always give me `null` in the `DoShowInStoreCommand`'s `url` argument? How do I use Command Parameters when binding `Element`s?

EDIT:

I tried the following, as what Slodge wrote in his answer does not match any of the Extension method signatures, but it is giving me errors when it tries to bind:

```
 new StringElement("Show in App Store")
                .Bind(bindings, "SelectedCommand CommandParameter(ShowInStoreCommand, TouchStoreUrl)")
```

error:

```
MvxBind: Error:   2.37 Problem parsing Lang binding MvxException: Must follow binding option CommandParameter with an '=' in SelectedCommand CommandParameter(ShowInStoreCommand, TouchStoreUrl)
      at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ParseEquals (System.String block) [0x0003c] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Parse\Binding\MvxBindingParser.cs:83 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseNextBindingDescriptionOptionInto (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxSerializableBindingDescription description) [0x0019a] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Parse\Binding\Swiss\MvxSwissBindingParser.cs:56 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Tibet.MvxTibetBindingParser.ParseNextBindingDescriptionOptionInto (Cirriou
s.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxSerializableBindingDescription description) [0x00033] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Parse\Binding\Tibet\MvxTibetBindingParser.cs:49 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseBindingDescription (ParentIsLookingForComma parentIsLookingForComma) [0x00014] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Parse\Binding\Swiss\MvxSwissBindingParser.cs:176 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseBindingDescription () [0x00001] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Parse\Binding\Swiss\MvxSwissBindingParser.cs:159 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ParseTargetPropertyNameAndDescription () [0x0000f] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Parse\Binding\MvxBindingParser.cs:72 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.TryParseBindingSpecification (System
.String text, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxSerializableBindingSpecification& requestedBindings) [0x0001a] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Parse\Binding\MvxBindingParser.cs:51
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding you've created in:

```
    new StringElement("Show in App Store").Bind(
                                  bindings, 
                                  e => e.SelectedCommand, 
                                  vm => vm.ShowInStoreCommand, 
                                 new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), ViewModel.TouchStoreUrl),
```

is a binding to the expression `vm => vm.ShowInStoreCommand` on the ViewModel, but it **captures** the current value of `ViewModel.TouchStoreUrl`

If you want to use MultiBinding in MvvmCross, then you can do this using the `Tibet` extensions (see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding) - but these are not easily accessible in the fluent Expression syntax - instead you have to use the string based syntax instead.

So this binding could be achieved using something like:

```
    new StringElement("Show in App Store").Bind(
                                  bindings, 
                                  e => e.SelectedCommand, 
                                  "CommandParameter(ShowInStoreCommand, TouchStoreUrl)")
```